# Create a migration to add the `admin` field to the `users` table

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

How to create migration to add the `admin` field to the `users` table with a boolean value and set default to false in Sinatra? I am using Active Record.

Comment: Sinatra isn't a database. What database are you using in your Sinatra app?

Comment: If you're using ActiveRecord => http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#ar-migrations

Comment: eg: DataMapper, ActiveRecord, Sequel. What library are you using to access your SQLite3 database?

Comment: I am using ActiveRecord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still just ActiveRecord, this would be no different than using it in Rails.

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :admin, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

You may also want to check out the sinatra-activerecord gem which will give you some extra rake tasks and makes things a little easier.

Here is also a useful article on using Sinatra with ActiveRecord.

[Sinatra and ActiveRecord](http://nycda.com/blog/integrating-activerecord-into-a-sinatra-project/)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too.

I solved it using `change_table` method instead of `add_column` so final code would look like:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.column :admin, :boolean, default: false
    end
  end
end
```